# BroadcastReceiver Life Cycle

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My Application has registered one receiver in Manifest file. What will happen to the Broadcast Receiver if my application process dies. Will it still be available and call my BroadcastReceiver class when the specified intent triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your `BroadcastReceiver` will continue to receive broadcasts even if your Activity is killed off.

Comment: Yep, if you declare your BroadcastReceiver statically in your manifest the intent will always trigger it. A new instance of your application is loaded into memory each time your BroadcastReceiver is called, and it is removed from memory after your receiver is finished doing whatever it needs to do. Might be useful to know if you have overridden your Application class since any data stored in it while your app is actually running will probably not be there when the receiver does its work.